# Expand Child Rows of Responsive Datatables automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have a responsive dataTable ([Responsive doc.](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/)) in the following format:

```
var dataTableInfo = j$('[id$="dataTableInfo"]').DataTable({
                 responsive: {
                    "autoWidth": true,
                    details: {
                        type: 'column',
                        target: 0
                    }
                },
                columnDefs: [ {
                    className: 'control',
                    orderable: false,
                    targets:   0
                } ]
            });
```

I fill this with data through a search to an external data source and I then have a second table inside the DataTable with additional data (in a child Row) that comes automatically from my instaniation. I can click on the icon in the first column to expand and show the child row, everything works fine.

What I want to accomplish is to automatically expand the child rows through Javascript of this DataTable, once all the data has been loaded (I know when this occurs in a callback function).

I have tried multiple variation of the following:

```
function ExpandTable(){
        var tab = j$('[id$="dataTableInfo"]').DataTable();
        alert(tab);

        tab.rows().every( function () {

            this.child.show();

        } );
    }
```

But my table simply won't expand its child rows. Nothing happens and no error messages in the console.

Can anyone help me in explaining how I for example can simulate a button click according to this:

```
$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
var child = table.row( this ).child;

if ( child.isShown() ) {
    child.hide();
}
else {
    child.show();
}} );
```

or in any other way automating this expanding of the child rows.

Ciao!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### CAUSE

It seems that Responsive plug-in does its own child row management, maybe that's why `row().child.show()` does not work.

#### SOLUTION

I am using undocumented `responsive._detailsDisplay()` method to trigger showing of a child row.

```
// Enumerate all rows
table.rows().every(function(){
    // If row has details collapsed
    if(!this.child.isShown()){
        // Expand row details
        table.settings()[0].responsive._detailsDisplay(this, false);
    }
});
```

#### EXAMPLE

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/2u650u18/) for code and demonstration.

#### LINKS

See [jQuery DataTables: jQuery DataTables: How to expand/collapse all child rows](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-how-to-expand-collapse-all-child-rows/#responsive) for more examples and information.

Comment: Thank you, I acctually tried a similar approach but must have had some issue in my selecor. This works.

Comment: Thank you very much for your example and link, it really helped me solving my problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can also add the class "parent" to rows on the row callback in the DataTable initialization:

```
 $('.table-container table').DataTable({
"rowCallback": function (row, data, index) {
  var that = row;

  if(!$(row).attr('role') || $(row).attr('role') != 'row' || $(row).hasClass('parent')){
    return;
  }

  $(row).addClass('parent');
}});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dhardin/omny3erh/)

This is the optimal method as you don't have to iterate through all rows post render. So instead of performing in O(n^2) you will be able to accomplish this in one fell swoop, i.e., O(n).

Comment: Thanks, this works much better than the accepted solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Since DataTables Responsive v2.0.0+ (released on Nov 2015)**

you can use the option `childRowImmediate` to show the child (collapsed data) immediately.

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    responsive: {
        details: {
            display: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.display.childRowImmediate,
            type: ''
        }
    }
} );
```

in the docs they have a [dedicated example](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-types/immediateShow.html) for this.

If you also want the toggle icon to remain use, set the `type` prop to `inline`:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    responsive: {
        details: {
            display: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.display.childRowImmediate,
            type: 'inline'
        }
    }
} );
```

Properties References: [type](https://datatables.net/reference/option/responsive.details.type), [display](https://datatables.net/reference/option/responsive.details.display)