# Create datatable showing childrows directly

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, datatables

I have created a datatable which shows the child rows using a button hide/show. Well I wanted to show the data right away without the button and do not want to add a button or maybe show the data by default and then have an option to hide it but preferably I would like to know something without use of button.

```
function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Full name:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.name+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extension number:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.extn+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extra info:</td>'+
            '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</table>';
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "http://localhost:8080/datatables/ajax/data/objects.txt",
        "columns": [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );

    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } );
} );
```

This code runs perfectly without any errors. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Could you please create a minimum verifiable example which we can run on either snippet/[codepen](https://codepen.io)/[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @PriyankPanchal [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vwbZNq) I have used Ajax to pull the data from. You can also find the working example here [link](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html)

Comment: I guess [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30924848/1955268) solves what you need. You can automate the button click or incorporate the functionality after datatable is initialized.

Comment: it still uses button to expand and show, would like to show the child rows directly without using anything else. Is that possible ? @PriyankPanchal

Comment: I have just modified the jsfiddle above to trigger a expand button click event at the end of document ready & on drawcallback. Check it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xnk23hrw/1/)

Comment: Thank you that worked for me. Can I know what did you use to do that ? Thanks @PriyankPanchal

Comment: It is a very crude way of solving your problem though. The link was just to give you a push to find a solution. There was already a button which expands all rows, I am triggering it on document ready event and also on drawcallback so that it remains open when you change page or do any other action with datatable. I would recommend you to find a better solution using the idea given in the link.